# How to set date in Winforms Datetimepicker

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-datetimepicker

I have Winform in which i have date time picker so I need to know how can I set default date value to 01 in datetime picker, and user cant change the date. How ever he/she can change the month or the year, but the default date remains the same ie; 01.

Comment: Are we talking about the jquery widget? Or winforms? Or wpf? Or Windows Phone? Or silverlight?

Comment: you need to write [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.textchanged.aspx) event for this.

Comment: @Mr_Green can you please explain how to do it

Comment: I think he wants to block out the "dd" part of the format

Comment: Sorry I was in Seminar... I can only give you idea use regular expressions (or whatever with you are satisfied) in combination with TextChanged event. yes block the "dd" part as mentioned by Derek. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pick some event that you will use. I did build string, but you can rewritte better code and much simpler. This is just an example for you to understand.

```
        int year = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text).Year;
        int month = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text).Month;
        dateTimePicker1.Text = DateTime.ParseExact("01." + month.ToString() + "." + year.ToString(), "dd.mm.yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

hope it helps